# is it possible to have transparent window using Direct2d and Win7?

Tags: winapi, alpha, direct2d, alpha-transparency

My system is Windows 7 and i want to use Direct2D for a toolkit project.

I want to create a window which is per-pixel transparent/translucent (we can see windows transparently or translucently which are below my window) in some parts of the window.

I've looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/june/windows-with-c-high-performance-window-layering-using-the-windows-composition-engine (see the image at the very bottom of this web page) and it seems that it is possible, but only with the extended window style WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP, which is not available on Win7 (only since win8).

I've tried to use a render target which is bgra with premultiplied alpha and an extended window style WS_EX_COMPOSITED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT without luck

here is my code (the relevant code, that is creation of render target and layout, is in the render() function):

```
#include <iostream>

#ifdef _WIN32_WINNT
# undef _WIN32_WINNT
#endif
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x602

#include <d2d1.h>

static HINSTANCE instance = NULL;
static HWND win = NULL;
static ID2D1Factory *factory = NULL;
static ID2D1HwndRenderTarget *rt = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK _window_procedure(HWND   window,
                                   UINT   message,
                                   WPARAM window_param,
                                   LPARAM data_param);

static void
render()
{
    RECT r;
    HRESULT res;

    /* render target */

    GetClientRect(win, &r);

    D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(r.right, r.bottom);

    FLOAT dpix;
    FLOAT dpiy;
    factory->GetDesktopDpi(&dpix, &dpiy);

    D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES rtp;
    rtp.type = D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_DEFAULT;
    rtp.pixelFormat.format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    rtp.pixelFormat.alphaMode = D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED;
    rtp.dpiX = dpix;
    rtp.dpiY = dpiy;
    rtp.usage = D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_USAGE_NONE;
    rtp.minLevel = D2D1_FEATURE_LEVEL_10;

    D2D1_HWND_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES wrtp;
    wrtp.hwnd = win;
    wrtp.pixelSize = size;
    wrtp.presentOptions = D2D1_PRESENT_OPTIONS_IMMEDIATELY;

    res =factory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(rtp, wrtp, &rt);

    if (FAILED(res))
    {
        std::cout << "CreateHwndRenderTarget failed" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    /* brush */
    ID2D1SolidColorBrush *brush;
    /* rgba */
    const D2D1_COLOR_F color = D2D1::ColorF(0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.5);
    res = rt->CreateSolidColorBrush(color, &brush);
    if (FAILED(res))
    {
        std::cout << "CreateSolidColorBrush failed" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    /* ellipse */
    D2D1_ELLIPSE ellipse;
    D2D1_SIZE_F sz = rt->GetSize();
    const float x = sz.width / 2;
    const float y = sz.height / 2;
    const float radius = std::min(x, y);
    ellipse = D2D1::Ellipse(D2D1::Point2F(x, y), radius, radius);

    rt->BeginDraw();

    rt->Clear( D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::SkyBlue, 0.5f) );
    rt->FillEllipse(ellipse, brush);

    rt->EndDraw();
}


LRESULT CALLBACK
_window_procedure(HWND   window,
                  UINT   message,
                  WPARAM window_param,
                  LPARAM data_param)
{
  switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
      PostQuitMessage(0);
      return 0;
    case WM_KEYUP:
      if (window_param == 'Q')
        {
          PostQuitMessage(0);
        }
      return 0;
      /* GDI notifications */
    case WM_PAINT:
      {
        RECT rect;

        std::cout << "paint" << std::endl;

        if (GetUpdateRect(window, &rect, FALSE))
          {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            BeginPaint(window, &ps);

            render();

            EndPaint(window, &ps);
          }
        return 0;
      }
    default:
      return DefWindowProc(window, message, window_param, data_param);
    }
}

int main()
{
    /* class */
    WNDCLASS wc;

    instance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    if (!instance)
        return 1;

    memset (&wc, 0, sizeof (WNDCLASS));
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = _window_procedure;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = instance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(1 + COLOR_BTNFACE);
    wc.lpszMenuName =  NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = "D2D";

    if(!RegisterClass(&wc))
        goto free_library;

    /* Window */
    int w;
    int h;
    RECT r;
    DWORD style;
    DWORD exstyle;

    w = 640;
    h = 480;

    style = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_SIZEBOX;
    exstyle = 0;
    exstyle |= WS_EX_COMPOSITED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
    //exstyle |= WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP;

    r.left = 0;
    r.top = 0;
    r.right = w;
    r.bottom = h;
    if (!AdjustWindowRectEx(&r, style, FALSE, exstyle))
        goto unregister_class;

    win = CreateWindowEx(exstyle,
                         "D2D", "Test",
                         style,
                         100, 100,
                         r.right - r.left,
                         r.bottom - r.top,
                         NULL,
                         NULL, instance, NULL);
    if (!win)
        goto unregister_class;

    ShowWindow(win, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

    /* factory */
    if (FAILED(D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED,
                                 &factory)))
      goto destroy_win;

    /* msg loop */
    while(1)
    {
        MSG msg;
        BOOL ret;

        ret = PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE);
        if (ret)
        {
            do
            {
                if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                  goto beach;
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessageW(&msg);
            } while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE));
        }
    }

 beach:
    factory->Release();
    DestroyWindow(win);
    UnregisterClass("D2D", instance);
    FreeLibrary(instance);

    return 0;

  destroy_win:
    DestroyWindow(win);
  unregister_class:
    UnregisterClass("D2D", instance);
  free_library:
    FreeLibrary(instance);

    return 1;
}
```

I also does not want to use layered windows.

does someone know if it is possible to achieve what I want on Windows 7 ?

thank you

Comment: Kenny Kerr had a good article on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/december/windows-with-c-layered-windows-with-direct2d

Comment: @JonathanPotter in this article, the layered windows are used, which i don't want, as i've said in my post.

Comment: If you proactively reject the solution then your problem has no solution.

Comment: i do not reject the solution, because it is not a solution : someone has proposed something that i don't want. You can't call this a solution. If someone tells me that what I want is really not possible, then, i'm ok with this.

Comment: @IInspectable just read the last 3 lines of my (non edited) post

Comment: Using a layered window *is* the solution on Windows 7. The fact that you don't want that to be the solution doesn't change that. Either use layered windows, don't support Windows 7, or simply drop the idea the a translucent window were to make for a good UI.

Comment: if it is the only solution, then it is sufficient for me; thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have a transparent window on Win7 without `WS_EX_LAYERED` style, but it have some disadvantages:

- window must have `WS_POPUP` style, othervise if Windows style have glass, background for window will be blured.
- DWM (Desktop Window Manager) on windows must be turned on, otherwise windows will be not transparent
- while window is transparent visualy, mouse click are not going throught 100% transparent area. Maybe there is solution for this, but I don't know any.

  ```
   // Transparent window setup
   #include <dwmapi.h>
   #pragma comment(lib, "Dwmapi")
   // ....

   MARGINS margins = { -1 };
   DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(m_hwnd, &margins);
   if (FAILED(D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &pFactory)))
   {
       return -1;
   }

   // ...

   hr = pFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(
       D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(
           D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_DEFAULT
           , D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED)
       )
       , D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(m_hwnd, size)
       , &pRenderTarget
   );
  ```

if your window is not transparent, you have probably turned off DWM or Windows doesn't have areo style set.

https://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/direct2d-and-the-desktop-window-manager